# Android background image, how to do it like the pro's?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-background

I'm searching how to get the same layoutbackground as for example Twitter or ToDoist. (When asked to log in) The background adapts to all sizes of screens perfectly.

The way I did it fills the entire screen making the background look odd because the whole image is on the screen.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background" >
```

I suppose I need to use different drawable maps and make different sized images? If yes how big should each image be?

I hope you understand my problem and would be pleased if anyone could give me good advice.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android and supporting multiple screens layouts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5432445/android-and-supporting-multiple-screens-layouts)