# Why does this layout work in preview but not on my device?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gridlayout

I am developing an Android application for school. The layout I worked out looks good for me on the preview of Android Studio, but as soon as I deploy it on my physical device (HTC One m8, Android 5.0.1), everything inside the cardview is messed up.

Layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="de.seschi98.trgapp.activities.ScheduleActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_schedule">



    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="120dp">


        <GridLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:columnCount="4"
            android:rowCount="1"
            android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:rowOrderPreserved="false">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lesson_number"
                android:text="01"
                android:textSize="22dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_columnWeight="20" />

            <GridLayout
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:columnCount="2"
                android:layout_columnWeight="90"
                android:rowCount="3"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">


                <TextView
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                    android:id="@+id/lesson_name"
                    android:text="Chemistry"
                    android:textSize="22dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:layout_row="0"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="15"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent" />

                <TextView
                    android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
                    android:id="@+id/teacher"
                    android:text="Mr Smith"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="16dp"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:layout_row="1"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="20"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent" />


                <TextView
                    android:gravity="top|center_horizontal"
                    android:id="@+id/room"
                    android:text="Room A-123"
                    android:textSize="16dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:layout_row="2"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="20"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent" />


            </GridLayout>

            <View android:layout_row="0"
                android:layout_column="2"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_columnWeight="15">

            </View>

            <View android:layout_row="0"
                android:id="@+id/badge"
                android:layout_column="3"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:background="#c0392b"
                android:layout_columnWeight="5">

            </View>


        </GridLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

[Preview Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/488DU.png)

[Device Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hou2L.png) (don´t matter about the action bar or other stuff, it´s only the CardView...)

// Update: Upgraded my Android version to 6.0.0 Marshmallow yesterday, now it is working fine. But I included the AppCompat thing... What could be the reason for it to not work on previous versions of Android?

Comment: Have you checked this on any other device or Emulator?

Comment: Same problem on my Samsung tablet with Android 5.0.2...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nevermind, it was a version error:

After some testing stuff I realized that I needed to change the `<GridLayout>` in my layout file to `<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>`. Didn´t think about that cause I thought GridLayout would be compatible with Android 5...

So now it is working fine on all my devices, as well Android 5 as Android 6.
Although it didn´t help me very much, thanks for the fast answers!

Comment: This solved things for me - thanks.  However, in order to be able to use the grid attributes like `app:columnCount="2"`, I need to set this as well: `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout"`

Answer (score 0):

The preview in android studio is sometimes different from your device, make sure to set the same screensize of your phone and the preview in android studio

Comment: I do not believe that it is the screen size, because I am using column and row weights so that it should fit the screen size...

Comment: @seschi98 - it's not bootstrap :)

Comment: @LinX64 yeah, i know, but I thought setting the gridLayout width to match_parent (100% so to say) and defining weights on the children would do the trick to make it kinda responsive

Comment: try to declare the padding and layout margin

Answer (score 0):

Kenny already gave you the answer.

Sometimes the preview is showing fine but on some devices it looks different. This usually happens because of the screensize and (or) your screen resolution.

You can add an specify layout for a screen size. But you must understand that android runs on an enormous variety of devices and screen sizes. You will always have troubles in some screens, maybe focusing on little design problems is not the way to go.

Check this links:

[Android And Supporting Mutiple Screens Layouts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5432445/android-and-supporting-multiple-screens-layouts?rq=1)

[Screens distribution](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html)

**EDIT:**

If you have the same problem in every device then it's probably that isn't about what we've already told. Let me check your code a little more and I'll tell you something else.

Comment: But I am working with weights and do not set any static values for widths/heights.... I don`t understand why this should matter...

Answer (score 0):

Alignment matters, me also had a same problem. I was setting just a single property **paddingLeft** but in some devices it won't work so I had to provide both property **paddingStart & paddingLeft** in styles-

```
<item name="android:paddingLeft">@dimen/drawable_icon_padding_left</item>
<item name="android:paddingStart">@dimen/drawable_icon_padding_left</item>
```

So make sure you are using both property in your layout or in styles. Happy coding :-)